# Preinitialize values for the component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, tags

I currently use a custom tag defined as follows:

```
<ui:composition>
    <ui:param name="value" value="#{value}" />
    <ui:param name="collection" value="#{collection}" />
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{value}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{collection}" />
        <f:converter binding="#{myConverter}"/> 
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</ui:composition>
```

the issue is for all facelets the value of the `#{collection}` attribute is going to be the same. Therefore I'd like to avoid boilerplate code in `ManagedBean`s to retrieve the same `List<SelectItem>`. Now, I tend to create a `ManagedBean` with the `ApplicationScope` that would be used only within the tag (i.e. its responsibility would be the only constructing the `List<SelectItem>`).

But I think it's contrary to incapsulation. The issue, is clients of the tag don't have to know about the bean. I would form it as a custom component with predefined values but it doesn't seem possible and correct from JSF-standpoint to execute an `sql`-query from the `UIComponent` class implementation (Constructing the `List<SelectItem>` requires to execute some `sql`-statements).

What woould be the most optimal solution for that?

Comment: Why can't you use <f:selectItems value="#{collectionBean.collection}" /> instead of #{collection} and don't pass collection as a parameter?

Comment: @A.Panzer Because it's not neccesary. The collection is the same.

Comment: I mean to create ApplicationScoped collectionBean and use it from your custom tag.

Comment: @A.Panzer I understood, but what's wrong with embedding the passing the collection into a custom tag?

Comment: First of all, I would encourage you not to use a `ui:composition` for this and using a JSF composite component instead. Then, if you don't want to access the application scoped managed bean in the implementation, you could pass the collection values as a parameter for the composite.